# Open custom file from Google Drive fails

Tags: android, google-drive-api

My application created files with a custom Mime type and stores them on Google Drive. The app can search and reopen these files just fine too. However, when I click the file in the Google Drive app (not my own app) the open flow does not work.

The Chooser Intent shows as expected with just my application listed, but when I select my application the Google Drive app briefly shows a downloading progress bar that never starts and then says there is an internal error.

My setup is below, I'm hoping somebody can tell me what causes this. although I would assume nothing is actually contacting my app by this point. The developer console has been filled in correctly as far as I know.

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="...">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/logo" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID" android:value="id=..." />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />
            <data android:mimeType="@string/app_mime" />
            <data android:mimeType="@string/file_mime" /> <!-- matches the file im clicking -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String ACTION_DRIVE_OPEN = "com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN";
private static final String EXTRA_DRIVE_OPEN_ID = "resourceId";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    handleIntent();
}

private void handleIntent() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (ACTION_DRIVE_OPEN.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        if (intent.getType().equals(getString(R.string.file_mime))) {
            String fileId = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DRIVE_OPEN_ID);
            if (fileId != null && !"".equals(fileId)) {
                ...
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Drive_Open has no valid file id - " + fileId);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Drive_Open called on the wrong mime type - " + intent.getType() + " found, " + getString(R.string.file_mime) + " required");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing this seems to happen after there is a timeout between the drive app connecting to the server to retrieve information and passing it to the other app (or any other fault).

The initial problem will give you a meaningful error but then the drive app seems to maintain a cache or something which cases the above error to be displayed on all future attempts.

The solution is to either clear the data of both apps (which can be problematic) or (I found easier) re-install the app you are developing/testing. Either method stops this problem reoccurring.